# Implicitly_wait() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm studying selenium with python and in a tutorial I found the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import gmtime, strftime
import unittest
#from builtins import classmethod

class RegisterNewUser(unittest.TestCase):
    #@classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        self.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")

    def test_register_new_user(self):
        driver = self.driver
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

It throw an error:

```
File "register_new_user.py", line 10, in setUp
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
TypeError: implicitly_wait() missing 1 required positional argument: 'time_to_wait'
```

I try to add the code commented out (`classmethod`) but doesn't change anything. Without the `test_register_new_user` doesn't give error.

I'm using python 3.6.4, selenium 3.141 (and geckodriver 0.23)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one line above:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox
```

This does not create a browser object. It just sets `self.driver` to the class `webdriver.Firefox`, which means that `self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)` is trying to use `implicitly_wait` in the static way, ie `webdriver.Firefox.implicitly_wait(30)`, so it is missing the instance, ie `webdriver.Firefox.implicitly_wait(an_actual_browser, 30)`.

You are missing `()`:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # which will potentially ask for a path to 
                                   # firefox/geckodriver if it is not in PATH, 
                                   # but that is out of the scope of this question
```

Comment: Since the question is based on basic _Python_ / _Selenium_ explaining `webdriver.Firefox.implicitly_wait(30)` will be overkill. IMO, the short and precise previous  version of the answer was perfecto !!!